# Chrome automatically fills in Stack Exchange comments

Tags: discussion

Help!  I contribute to the Physics Stack Exchange.  I use Chrome (on OS X), and I don't use any extensions with stack exchange.

For the last several days, when I attempt to leave a comment on a post, Chrome has been automatically filling the comment space with text that I submitted as a comment days ago.  Editing is a nightmare, because with every edit *all* of the text I entered is deleted, and that old text is inserted in its place.  Practically anything I do in the comment field causes all text to be deleted, and that old scrap of text to be inserted.  Any help?

Comment: For future reference, support questions about Stack Exchange itself should go on the meta site for the site where you're having issues. In this case, that would be [meta.physics.se].

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic, it should be directed to [pysics.se/meta]

Answer (score 1):

Check your browser auto-fill settings, it certainly isn't the stack exchange, must be the browser (or browser extension).

Try removing extensions one at a time, re-checking if  the issue exists after each.

Comment: The checkbox next to "Enable Autofill to fill out web forms in a single click." Is not checked, and never has been. This is crazy. Anything else I should look for?

Comment: Crazy indeed, you said you don't use extensions with stack exchange, do use ANY browser extensions?

Comment: Beyond crazy: I recently added a text-to-speech converter. I needed it only for a certain special purpose, and don't need it any more.  I deleted it, and the problem went away!!  We'll see if it sticks.

Comment: Glad you figured it out :-)

Comment: so much for "I dont use any extensions" ;)